# How to create a Java Function list?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I want to create a list from Java `Function`s. But When I try to add a function to `functions` list, it says;

```
Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I don't get which method is static. Is there any idea?

My Main class:

```
public void createFunctionList() {
    List<Function> functions = new ArrayList<>();
    functions.add(Product::getInfo);
}
```

My product class:

```
public class Product 
{
    public Info getInfo() {
        return info;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do `Product::getInfo` you make a reference to the function getInfo in the class Product. And thus without using an instance. So java is expecting getInfo to be static

Comment: Do you mean a Java Function or the Method of a Class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Product::getInfo` can be assigned to a `Function<Product,Info>` (since it's a non-static method, so it can be seen as a function that takes a `Product` instance and returns an `Info` instance). Change the declaration of `functions` from

```
List<Function> functions = new ArrayList<>();
```

to

```
List<Function<Product,Info>> functions = new ArrayList<>();
```

EDIT: I tested your code, and I get a different compilation error:

> The type Product does not define getInfo(Object) that is applicable here.

The compilation error you got is misleading.
Once I make the suggested change, the error goes away.

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem. `getInfo` should be static to be referenced with `Product::getinfo`

Comment: @Héctor method references can refer to non static methods. A static method wouldn't fit the `Function` interface, since it would have a return type but no input argument.

Comment: Of course, but a `this` reference is needed, when it's not static.

Comment: @Héctor it's not needed. `this` is only needed if you want the method reference to refer to a specific instance of the class.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. But problem is I need to add some other functions as well like Supply::getInfo, Info::getAddress. Is there a generic way to create a function list?

Comment: @hellzone do you want a `List<Function<Object,Object>>`? That's not type safe. Each function expects a specific type of input and produces a specific type of output. If you do use a `List<Function<Object,Object>>`, you can add functions to it such as `functions.add(p -> ((Product)p).getInfo());`, but that casting is not safe.